# Is There A Way To Backup Visual Studio Team Services Projects?

Tags: version-control, tfs, azure-devops

I'm advocating using Visual Studio Team Services for our source control solution, and have actually started doing so. However, my manager, who is somewhat apprehensive when it comes to cloud-hosted storage and services, wants to know what our contingency plan is in the event of Team Services ceasing to be accessible for whatever reason.

I've pointed out that we have our source code on our developers' computers, in their mapped work spaces, but admittedly if we ended up with just that and no access to Team Services we'd certainly be in a bit of bind.  They might all be working on different parts of the same solution and we wouldn't be able to check all of their changes back into the central repository or merge changes made in separate branches.  We also wouldn't have access to the comments associated with previous check-ins, or our backlog, tests, etc.

So, the question is, is there a way to backup everything that we're hosting in Team Services so that, in the event of something going wrong, we'd be able to restore all of that to a locally-hosted installation of TFS (or somewhere else)?

Comment: Does have it integration wth TFS online?

Comment: Visual Studio Online is what TFS Online (or Team Foundation Service) is now called. It's the same thing.

Comment: Ah. You could in theory write a powershell script to sync from the Project to a local machine and have the code available should the lights go out.

Comment: I believe VSO's longest outage in the last 2 years is about 4 hours, so you should probably not have to worry too much. That being said, are you on TFVC or Git for source control, and do you want to back up only source, and/or work items as well?

Comment: Thanks Andrew. My colleague is more concerned with something like Microsoft shutting down the service altogether than just short-term outages. We're using TFVC and yes, we'd like to back up everything, including work items, etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm a bit late to the party but we developed a Team Services backup tool. We scheduled it as a scheduled task and it runs once a night. It then just clones all our repositories to disk.

Taken from [this blog](http://blog.orbitone.com/post/Visual-Studio-Online-Backup-Tool):

> We use the VSO Rest API  to query our VSO account and get all the data
>   we need. Since in VSO you can only have one Team Project Collection,
>   we retrieve all the team projects of the default collection. Each of
>   these team projects can have multiple repositories that need to be
>   backed up. A folder is created for each team project and saved to a
>   location on disk that can be configured in the app.config. When the
>   team project folder is created, the task loops over each repository in
>   the team project and creates folders for each repository.

You can also fork it on GitHub [here](https://github.com/OrbitOne/VSOBackup)

Answer (score 5):

There's no out of the box backup ability.

Now, if you are *only* referring to source control, and not work items, pull requests, builds, test plans or anything else that the service offers, then I'd suggest you migrate your code over to git.

With git every developer will have a complete copy of the source repository, including all history and commit comments. From there, it's a simple task to push the git repository to a different git hoster (such as bitbucket or github) and make them your new centrally hosted git repository.

On a historical note, Visual Studio Team Services at one point offered a data export for a period of time. You might want to add a vote or three to [this related UserVoice idea](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2264946-import-export-data-from-visual-studio-online) to help raise the importance of the feature with Microsoft.

Side comment: The business risks in using Visual Studio Team Services will come from either Microsoft shutting down the Visual Studio Team Services service or that the underlying Azure infrastructure has such a catastrophic failure that your Visual Studio Team Services account is unrecoverable.  Both of those are extremely low risk, and very likely lower than the risks you'd have running TFS on-premises, in your own data centre, unless of course, your infrastructure and staff are better than Microsoft's :-)

Comment: Indeed any shutdown of either from MSFT would come with significant lag time to allow folks to get their stuff out. In such a circumstance the TFS teams ould let you take your data on-premises I am sure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm reluctant to migrate to git, having just got our TFVC solution nicely set up, but it sounds like something I'll have to look into. That still wouldn't solve the problem of backing up everything else (work items etc.), though. I realise that a sudden discontinuation of the service is highly unlikely and an on-premises solution would likely be more at risk, all things considered, but my management are right to question me on the risks.  I've voted for that feature, thanks for the tip.

Comment: VSO isn't going anywhere unless MS goes under completely.

Comment: How about the case when I can make a mistake myself? I would like to have a way to backup (mainly source control) so I can make some not very frequent changes (like moving files, folders, renaming projects) that may lead to problems if mistakes are made.

Comment: @PhilipStratford: I don't know whether you saw the [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30149993/722393), but it looks like someone's taken the initiative to write a backup tool for these very reasons. There still might be some outstanding issues related to full support by the API, as discussed in the reviews for [this VS add-in](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/28a90a17-d00c-4660-b7ae-42d58315ccf2), but they may have been resolved by now. I'm still investigating.

Comment: I think the "business risks" comment is redundant. Having multiple copies of a repo and all its commit history, rather than a single copy significantly reduces the risk to almost 0. When it comes to protecting IP, 2 copies is always better than 1! It's true that redundancy will be built into VSTS/DevOps with multiple backups etc, but they are all still off-premises. Having a backup on-premises just makes sense...

Answer (score 1):

Not a full VS backup in terms of a restore of service.  But you can take a full Zip from root down using the Code web site.  Right click the root folder and has a zip download option. Pretty neat feature.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to back up everything is to use something like the TFS Integration Platform to periodically pull off all your data into an on-premises TFS solution. I've set this up using an Azure VM that we turned off when we weren't actively backing up, which makes it really low cost. For more info on using the TFS IP with Team Services, see this: http://nakedalm.com/migration-from-tf-service-to-tf-server-with-the-tfs-integration-platform/

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That link is useful, although it doesn't sound like a simple task! Also, whilst your solution sounds pretty slick, presumably you needed a TFS licence for your VM? Ideally, we'd just want the data as a backup, and only pay for a TFS licence if we ever needed to actually replace VSO, rather than pay for both at the same time.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I believe you would only need to license TFS if you were actually using it for source control.