# Visual Studio Online Local Backup?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I work from a small IT department and I'm pushing to move from our current TFS implementation to Visual Studio Online. My boss who gets the final say is hesitant because *"What if Microsoft decides to stop offering the service, without notice, or their servers fail how will we get our code"*. While I find such a scenario unlikely and the scenario of our TFS server crashing and burning with no backups/bad backups much more likely. I still need to address his concern.

Does anyone know of a way to "backup" a remote TFS implementation? So far the only thing I've come up with is doing a nightly pull of Visual Studio Online and submitting it to a local repo, feels hacky, feels wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look over at the discussion on this StackOverflow question:  [Is There A Way To Backup Visual Studio Team Services Projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27000001/is-there-a-way-to-backup-visual-studio-online-projects)

Here is Richard's answer:

> There's no out of the box backup ability.
>
> Now, if you are only referring to source control, and not work items,
>   pull requests, builds, test plans or anything else that the service
>   offers, then I'd suggest you migrate your code over to git.
>
> With git every developer will have a complete copy of the source
>   repository, including all history and commit comments. From there,
>   it's a simple task to push the git repository to a different git
>   hoster (such as bitbucket or github) and make them your new centrally
>   hosted git repository.
>
> On a historical note, Visual Studio Online at one point offered a data
>   export for a period of time. You might want to add a vote or three to
>   [this related UserVoice idea](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2264946-import-export-data-from-visual-studio-online) to help raise the importance of the
>   feature with Microsoft.
>
> Side comment: The business risks in using Visual Studio Online will
>   come from either Microsoft shutting down the Visual Studio Online
>   service or that the underlying Azure infrastructure has such a
>   catastrophic failure that your Visual Studio Online account is
>   unrecoverable. Both of those are extremely low risk, and very likely
>   lower than the risks you'd have running TFS on-premises, in your own
>   data centre, unless of course, your infrastructure and staff are
>   better than Microsoft's :-)

I agree with Richard.  Visual Studio Online is not going anywhere :)  You can also use tools like OpsHub, TaskTop, and Kovair to setup a two-way synchronization or use the TFS Integration Platform to do the same thing if you really wanted an option.  If you are using Git repositories, you can clone the repository into other locations to maintain multiple copies. All of those options take effort.

Comment: Well there is one more risk, identity theft is a potential larger risk, Microsoft will not bring back any data if deleted by administrator !!

Comment: @AkashKava - that's not exactly true.  I'm no longer with Microsoft but if you do happen to delete something accidentally, you can reach out to the support team and ask them to restore an earlier backup to help you recover the data.

Answer (score 2):

I posted the same answer to this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27000001/is-there-a-way-to-backup-visual-studio-online-projects).

> We developed our own VSO backup tool. We scheduled it as a scheduled task and it runs once a night. It then
>   just clones all our repositories to disk.
>
> Taken from [this blog](http://blog.orbitone.com/post/Visual-Studio-Online-Backup-Tool):
>
> > We use the VSO Rest API  to query our VSO account and get all the data
> >     we need. Since in VSO you can only have one Team Project Collection,
> >     we retrieve all the team projects of the default collection. Each of
> >     these team projects can have multiple repositories that need to be
> >     backed up. A folder is created for each team project and saved to a
> >     location on disk that can be configured in the app.config. When the
> >     team project folder is created, the task loops over each repository in
> >     the team project and creates folders for each repository.
>
> You can also fork it on GitHub [here](https://github.com/OrbitOne/VSOBackup)