# Configure a backup schedule for Git version control with VSTS

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I found articles on GIT back up and restore but I did not find any on Microsoft TFS Scheduled backup for GIT version control.

This document describes on how TFS's traditional versioning can be scheduled for automatic back up. [Configure a backup schedule and plan for Team Foundation Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/backup/config-backup-sched-plan?view=tfs-2018)

However, I did not find any link where I can read that "GIT repository is also included in schedule". I am not a TFS expert and I do not have access to TFS server to verify in person. So any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which one are you actually talking about on-premise TFS or  online VSTS? If you are using VSTS as your title, the tutorial is not apply to it. VSTS do not have  TFS Administration console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial you are refer which is **Scheduled Backups tool**. It' a  build-in tool on the Scheduled Backups page in the TFS Administration console.

It' the whole **database back up**  not only referring to source control, but also work items, pull requests, builds, test plans or anything else that the service offers.

As a limitation, you need both an administrator for TFS and a member of the SQL Server System Administrators group.

And no need to to verify in person, it's under SQL server, when you want to use the backup, just restore the database.

---

If you are actually using the online **VSTS** . For now there is no build-in tool and got a uservoice:

> ***Provide a backup service for Visual Studio Team Services***
>
> https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/5339461-provide-a-backup-service-for-visual-studio-team-se

However if  you just want a git repository(source code) back up, you could use some 3rd-party tool to achieve this:

> We use the VSO Rest API  to query our VSO account and get all the data
>   we need. Since in VSO you can only have one Team Project Collection,
>   we retrieve all the team projects of the default collection. Each of
>   these team projects can have multiple repositories that need to be
>   backed up. A folder is created for each team project and saved to a
>   location on disk that can be configured in the app.config. When the
>   team project folder is created, the task loops over each repository in
>   the team project and creates folders for each repository.
>
> *[Source Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27000001/is-there-a-way-to-backup-visual-studio-team-services-projects)*

You can also fork it on GitHub [here](https://github.com/OrbitOne/VSOBackup). Certainly, you should also be able to use this for on-premise TFS also use the API, just need to change some part.

Answer (score 2):

TFS is implemented the way to keep Git repositories in the SQL Server database, too. Thus, when you follow the instructions from the article you reference, the source code will also be included in the backup, no difference whether it is TFVC or Git.